# Why IWSDLPublish interface is added to Win32 Delphi WebService

Tags: web-services, delphi

I've created a simple CGI application using Delphi 2009 that publishes a web service. When I point my web browser to the app, I can see my web service interface and another interface: IWSDLPublish.

Why is this interface added to my web service?
Do I need it?
Is it possible to not publish this interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

That's what's used to display the WSDL for your interface. If you remove the WSDLPublish component, it should no longer publish that interface.

Comment: But then I don't have WSDL for my service either. Any other options? :)

Comment: Not that I know of. The purpose of the IWSDLPublish interface is to publish the WSDL. No IWSDLPublish, no WSDL. Sorry!